# Jest Manual Mocks with React and Typescript: mock an ES6 class dependency

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, jestjs

I am using React with Typescript and in a unit test I have to mock a module which is included inside the main file to which I am writing unit tests for (a container component).

The file I am trying to test imports this module:

```
import PerformancesResultsReader from './../../models/PerformancesResultsReader';
```

and then it uses the module in the following way:

```
const performancesResultsReader = new PerformancesResultsReader();
performancesResultsReader.read();
```

This file is called `AppPage.component.tsx`

The test file is located in the same folder and when I use the automatic mock, it works as expected. The automatic mock is implemented simply through the `jest mock` of the same import:

```
jest.mock('./../../models/PerformancesResultsReader');
```

In this way all the methods simply return `undefined`.

Now I was trying to add a manual mock instead of the automatic one.

This is the `PerformancesResultsReader.js` mock code:

```
console.log('including mock!');

const mock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
        read: () => {
            console.log('mocked');
        }
    };
});

export default mock;
```

I tried to place it inside a `__mocks__` sub folder in the same level of the file I am testing, and I tried to put it also in the same folder of the imported module I want to mock.
In both cases it doesn't seem to be called at all (the first console log never gets printed).

Any idea about what I am doing wrong please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found the way to make it work.

There are few steps needed in order to sort it out:

1. When you're mocking your dependency, you can place your `__mock__` folder or at the same level of the main file you're testing which imports it, or at the same level of the class you are going to mock
2. In your unit tests file, the call to `jest.mock` must happen before you include your main file to be tested, the one which requires the file to be mocked

So, the code is the following.

Main file to be unit tested (`AppPage.component.tsx`):

```
// all imports
import PerformancesResultsReader from './../../models/PerformancesResultsReader'; // dependency to be mocked

// your AppPage component here
export default AppPage;
```

Mock inside the `__mock__` sub folder (`PerformancesResultsReader.tsx`):

```
class PerformancesResultsReader {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Mock constructor');
    }
    // all your methods here
}

export default PerformancesResultsReader;
```

And the final unit test (`AppPage.component.spec.tsx`):

```
// call the defined mock
jest.mock('./../../models/PerformancesResultsReader');
// import the main file which is going to be tested
import AppPage from './AppPage.component';

describe('App Container Component', () => {
    // your tests
});
```

The folders structure of the above example is the following:

```
- components
-- AppPage.component.tsx
-- AppPage.component.spec.tsx
- models
-- PerformancesResultsReader.tsx
-- __mock__
--- PerformancesResultsReader.tsx
```

Comment: It helped! Thank you :D For me the problem was file import order, I've imported `jest.mock()` after file that needed to be tested.

Comment: @Arcagully I am happy it helped someone esle, it made sense the time I "wasted" for publishing the solution to my own problem :D